# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rio’

Tags: r, r-rio

I'm unable to load the rio package. I already have it installed.

```
library(rio)
```

Here's the full error below:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rio’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘foreign’

Comment: Do you have the foreign package installed?

Comment: I tried installing foreign but it's not available for my version of R (3.6.1)

Comment: Strange, I have R 3.6.2 and could install foreign

Comment: I got it working by redownloading R from Cran. I originally installed it from anaconda navigator that might have something to do with it?